# How to hide certain levels of headings in the PDF ToC converted from Typora

Tags: css, pdf, markdown

I am using Typora to convert a Markdown file into a PDF.
In this file I used one H1 heading and several H5 and H6 headings.
What I want to achieve is that in the final PDF converted from this markdown file, I want all H5 and H6 headings hidden from the table of content panel on the left side of my PDF viewer.
I tried by adding the following code into the CSS stylesheet and putting a `[toc]` at the beginning of my markdown file right under the title:

```css
.md-toc-h6 {
  display: none;
}
.md-toc-h5 {
  display: none;
}
```

This attempt failed, not only hiding h5 and h6 headings from my Table of Content, but also wiping them out from the PDF text. I want to hide them in the table of content but keep them in the text.

Can anyone let me know if this is doable and how?

What I want to achieve is that in the final PDF converted from this markdown file, I want all H5 and H6 headings hidden from the table of content panel on the left side of my PDF viewer but kept in the text.